# Resize icons in WordPress header

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to make these social media icons larger in my Wordpress menu.

[image: Icon issue]

I used this code as a custom link in the menu:

```
<i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
```

Comment: Check the `class="fa fa-instagram"` css I think there will be the size, if not you will have to take a look into the icons, getting another bigger or scalling it

Answer (score 0):

`fa` stands for [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/), so your icons are a font. You can change their size by using `font-size` in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

just add font size to parent HTML tag. It'll works.

```css
a { font-size: 100px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
```